# XML to JSON using XSLT on selected nodes

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I am in middle of my development, I have an XML response for which i have to convert to JSON, Using data mapper i am able to convert it, But i am facing issue when converting some of the xml nodes, all

```
<avalues>
```

are not showing up in json.

For Eg my xml response is

```
<data>
    <avalue1>1</avalue1>
    <avalue2>2</avalue2>
    <avalue3>3</avalue3>
    <data>
```

and i want to convert it as below

> { 
>       "cn": 
>       { 
>       "avalue1": "1", 
>       "avalue2": "2", 
>       "avalue3": "3" 
>       },

```
}
```

i am using xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/avalue"> <avalue> <xsl:value-of select="(.,'string')[. ne ''][1]"/> </avalue> </xsl:for-each>
```

thanks--

Comment: _"i am facing issue"_ -- you have not stated what the issue is.  [edit] your post and show what you expect, what the actual output is, and what is wrong.

Comment: Also explain which software/"data mapper" exactly you use/are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you XML can be not only with one `data` block, so for visible example I took your part into XML as below (**edited**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cn>
    <data>
        <avalue1>1</avalue1>
        <avalue2>2</avalue2>
        <avalue3>3</avalue3>    
    </data>
    <data>
        <avalue4>4</avalue4>
        <avalue5>5</avalue5>
        <avalue6>6</avalue6>    
    </data>
</cn>
```

So, in XSL you can firstly create your string per data block and then combine them all as below (**edited**):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="text" />    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output">
            <xsl:for-each select="/cn/data">
                <xsl:variable name="avalues">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <!--create string per data as e.g. "avalue1": "1", "avalue2": "2", "avalue3": "3" -->                    
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', name(), '&quot;',': ', '&quot;', ., '&quot;', ', ')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <!--combine per each data block-->
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('{ ', substring($avalues, 0, string-length($avalues)-1), ' },')"/> 
            </xsl:for-each>            
        </xsl:variable>
        <!--perform final result with required format-->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{', '&quot;', 'cn', '&quot;', ':[', substring($output, 1, string-length($output)-1), ']}')"/>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result (**edited**) will be as expected (in final `value-of` you can add your own format - spaces, signs etc.):

```
{"cn":[
    { "avalue1": "1", "avalue2": "2", "avalue3": "3" },
    { "avalue4": "4", "avalue5": "5", "avalue6": "6" }
]}
```

Comment: That result does not look like JSON to me. Admittedly the poster did not even manage to show any well-formed input but your attempt to simply separate `{ "avalue1": "1", "avalue2": "2", "avalue3": "3" },{ "avalue4": "4", "avalue5": "5", "avalue6": "6" }` by comma does not result in JSON.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Main goal of my answer is to show/help to understand how to get from mentioned XML (even extended one) result as mentioned with help of XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have edited example more close for JSON format, thanks for attention.